# How to open a .nib file in a "popup" window , iOS?

Tags: ios, popup, nib, popupwindow

i have a .nib file in my application that i would like to show it to the user as a "popup" window.

I would like to have a result like this :

[image]

Here you can see an empty "popup" window with an X for closing.To be accurate this is an [MT popup Window](http://www.touch-code-magazine.com/showing-a-popup-window-in-ios-class-for-download/) but sadly you can only load it with html and not with a view , like a .nib file.

Does anyone know how i could create a popup window like this to show a .nib file or have a ready 3rd party solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A custom UIView is what you want my friend.

So create a class that has the super UIView.

Create a an objective-c Class call. For example I call mine *CustomView*

Your Header(.h)

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface CustomView : UIView

@end
```

Your class(.m)
    #import "CustomView.h"

```
@implementation CustomView

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{ 
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
    // Initialization code
    [self loadNib];
    }
    return self;
}

- (void) loadNib
{
    NSArray * subviewArray = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"MyNib" owner:self options:nil];
    UIView * mainView = [subviewArray objectAtIndex:0];

    [self addSubview:mainView];

}
- (IBAction)close:(id)sender{
     [self removeFromSuperview];
}
@end
```

Now in your ViewController call and add your custom view. You many want this in a IBAction(button click etc).

```
 CGRect frame = CGRectMake(10,10,300, 460);
 CustomView *view = [[CustomView alloc] initWithFrame:frame]; 
 [self.view addSubview:view];
```

When your custom view is added to your main view it will have loaded the nib.

EDIT:To have the x close it. In you customView have a IBACTION and just say
  [self removeFromSuperView];
You may want to setup a delegate communicating with your controller to do something on when view on closes etc.

Want a to be able to tap the off custom view to close it, create a `UIView` put a `UITapGestureRecognizer` on it that closes your custom view and place it underneath your custom view and cover the whole screen.

Hope this helps,

BooRanger

Comment: Thank you very much for your help but sadly i dont understand. If you could give me some sample working code would be better. Just like this i am not sure where to place the code.

Comment: @d0nparalias Hey I updated my answer hopefully its more understandable but if not you should be able to find something on Google about it, creating a custom UIView with a nib/xib